# loomiere http streaming server

Tags: lua, pcre, luarocks

I try to install a instance of loomiere a http streaming server for our campus. The compiling of the needed components runs fine without any error.

```
- Lua(5.1) ............ _http://www.lua.org/
- Luarocks ............ _http://www.luarocks.org/
    - alt-getopt ...... _http://luaforge.net/projects/alt-getopt/
    - lpeg ............ _http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/lpeg/lpeg.html
    - luabitop ........ _http://bitop.luajit.org/
    - lua-ev .......... _http://github.com/brimworks/lua-ev
    - lrexlib-pcre .... _http://lrexlib.luaforge.net/
    - luasocket ....... _http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/
- LibEV ............... _http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html
- PCRE ................ _http://www.pcre.org
- TokyoCabinet ........ _http://fallabs.com/tokyocabinet/
```

On running the loomiere executable I get the following error:

```
[root@mediakescher-01 loomiere]# ./run
Loomiere (HTTP streaming server) version 2.0.1-beta.
Copyright (C)2010 PaloÅ & Sons. All rights reserved.
PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API (error loading module 'rex_pcre' from file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/rex_pcre.so':
        /usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/rex_pcre.so: undefined symbol: lua_getmetatable)
[root@mediakescher-01 loomiere]#
```

The module rex_pcre was installed by using luarocks install function. I found some hints that the dynamic linker was not configured correctly. Because of installing the module as a rock I have no possibilities to change the install behaviour.

What can I do to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

ASsuming you are building on Ubuntu, I would suggest you ensure you have libpcre-dev installed.

```
# apt-get install libpcre-dev
```

I also had some troubles getting lrexlib-pcre to build and solved that with:

```
# luarocks install lrexlib-pcre PCRE_LIBDIR=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

Hope that helps !